GeoServer Tile Layer re-seeding taking a lot of time
I am using AWS EC2 instance with 16 CPU and 32 GB of RAM.
I have configured a tile layer with file blob storage and generated tiles from LOD 0 to LOD 15. The tile generation takes about 2 hours and 30 minutes for approximately 500,000,000 tiles.
This layer was updated with new data and I tired re-seeding the layer.
For some reason some threads were terminated and for the remaining LOD GWC is suggesting processing time between 8 to 21 days.
All 16 CPUs are running on 20% average.
How can I run the re-seeding faster?


Seeding 500,000,000 in 2:30 minutes feels unreasonable. Are you sure that all the tiles were generated initially?

do you really need to seed to that depth? do any of your users look at all the tiles?

The customer wants a very heavy polygon layer which is around 1 GB to render fast. Yes the customer wants to view the layer at depth.

@user30184 small correction there its 2 hours and 30 minutes

Thanks for the correction. If the difference is real then deleting old tiles takes quite a lot of time. A workabound might be to forget reseeding that takes 3 weeks, and just seed again and spend 3 hours for that.
